# Can't access Identity Provider in Azure App Service Authentication menu

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-roles, azure-role-environment

When i try to access the 'Authentication' menu in Azure App Service, I get a message saying I don't have access to this.

I don't want to use the built-in roles like 'Contributor' or 'Owner'. I have created a custom role, with granular permissions but i can't find the specific permission that deals with Azure App Service authentication.

What permissions do I need to attach to a custom role, so I can access the Authentication menu, and add an identity provider?

Comment: What is the role you have in azure account?

Comment: it's a custom role but bunch of permissions for granular level access. i am looking for permission that would let me add and access the authentication menu on app service, this permission would be updated on the custom role by admin so i can  access it

Answer (score 0):

Double-check what OAuth permissions are granted to **App Configuration Data Owner** and **App Configuration Data Reader** in Azure AD, that should give you an indication of what permissions to assign to your custom role.